# How to link to a fediverse/Mastodon account in HTML?

Tags: html

When I want to link to an email from a webpage, I use `mailto:` like

```
<a href="mailto:user@domain.org">Mail me!</a>
```

Now, how to link to a federated [Mastodon](https://joinmastodon.org/) handle like `@user@domain.org`? I can get around the problem by linking the webpage of the user (`domain.org/@user`), but I wonder whether there is a way to let the client handle the link using user's preferred client, just like in the case of e-mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no.  I asked about a URI scheme in the early days - see https://mastodon.social/@Edent/2094622

It might be nice to have `mastodon://mastodon.social/@edent` - but that link just wouldn't work for anyone who didn't have an app which could handle it.

The web has won. Everything is an `https://` link now - with some legacy exceptions like `tel:` and `mailto:`

So, what's the solution?

When your web browser makes an HTTP request to a Mastodon server, this HTTP header is returned (formatted for clarity):

```
server: Mastodon
...
link:
  <https://mastodon.social/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct%3AEdent%40mastodon.social>;
  rel="lrdd";
  type="application/xrd+xml", <https://mastodon.social/users/Edent.atom>;
  rel="alternate";
  type="application/atom+xml", <https://mastodon.social/users/Edent>; 
  rel="alternate"; 
  type="application/activity+json"
```

If the server name doesn't give your browser a clue which app to open, hopefully the webfinger stuff, or alternate links, will.